# How to pass answers to CLI script via arguments?

Tags: command-line

I'm writing a CLI script that asks a series of questions before doing a few things. How can I pass them as arguments so that I don't have to keep entering them every time I want to test my script?

Basically, it should pass 4 items to STDIN, like "text1[ENTER]text2[ENTER]text3[ENTER]text4[ENTER]" automatically.

Yes, I could modify my script to actually read the shell arguments, but I don't want to do it that way, since it's supposed to run more like a wizard.

Looking for something like

```
SOMEPROGRAM myscript arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

or

```
SOMEPROGRAM arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 | myscript
```

Or something like that. Is there such a program?

Answer (score 6):

I understand you do not want to modify `myscript`.

Regarding the second solution you ask for, you can use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' text1 text2 text3 text4 | myscript
```

so that, defining an alias for SOMEPROGRAM as:

```
alias SOMEPROGRAM="printf '%s\n'"
```

you could effectively call

```
SOMEPROGRAM text1 text2 text3 text4 | myscript
```

The first form is ambiguous (from the point of view of SOMEPROGRAM), because it don't know where `myscript` options end and text parameters start, unless `myscript` is effectively invoked without any options. In this case you could use a function:

```
SOMEPROGRAM() {
  myscript="$1"
  shift
  printf '%s\n' "$@" | "$myscript"
}
```

so that you could effectively call

```
SOMEPROGRAM myscript text1 text2 text3 text4
```

Comment: Haha...you didn't have to make it verbatim :p `printf` solution looks good, I'll have to try this on monday!

Comment: for the printf solution I get `stty: stdin isn't a terminal`

Comment: @Mark: ok, not all programs accept indifferently stdin or interactive input. What is your `myscript`?

Comment: It's a PHP script that takes input in via `$fp=fopen("php://stdin","r")` and `fgets($fp)`

Comment: @Mark: I have no php knowledge, but I wonder why the `stty` string in the error message. It could be useful to see a stripped down, but complete, version of `myscript` that still presents the problem.

Comment: I'll see if I can post one for you tomorrow. I can't post too much because I think it's company property and I'll probably get in trouble :p I didn't realize there was a distinction between `stdin` and `terminal` otherwise I probably would have tagged this as PHP and posted it on Stackoverflow instead.

Answer (score 2):

So basically, you want to pass each argument as a line to a child program. Below is a script that loops through all arguments passed ti `SOMEPROGRAM` and prints them as a line. You can pass an empty line ("enter without entering something before") by passing an empty argument as in `SOMEPROGRAM yes '' | myscript`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is "SOMEPROGRAM", it prints each argument as "answer" to  a program that
# must be piped. Usage: SOMEPROGRAM yes 1 no 2 | myscript
for arg; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

If you always need to answer "yes" to your script, use the coreutil `yes`:

```
yes | myscript
```

If you need to pass some other value, say "no":

```
yes 'no' | myscript
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash, you can do this:

```
myscript << END
arg1 
arg2
arg3
arg4
END
```

or

```
myscript <<< $'arg1\narg2\narg3\narg4\
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameters, but it won't work, you'll also have to modify the bash script to accept the params from the command-line as well.

Comment: Why's that? It's just reading in 4 things from STDIN one at a time, and you *can* pass things into STDIN...so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a script then just use getopts so the arguments are passed to the scripts and then you can use those args as you want? Is this something you are looking for?

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Comment: I'm just going to quote myself here... "Yes, I could modify my script to actually read the shell arguments, but I don't want to do it that way, since it's supposed to run more like a wizard."

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, the way enzotib describes it with piping stdin from a file seems reasonable. Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "What's your name?" name 
echo $name 
read -p "Age?" age 
echo $age
echo "Your name is " $name " and your age is "$age
```

invoke it with:

```
echo -e "Foobar\n14\n" | ./namenage.sh
```

The -e is to enable escape sequences like `\n`ewline.

```
Foobar
14
Your name is  Foobar  and your age is 14
```

Note how magically, bash doesn't print the prompt for reading.

However, for more complicated cases, there is a program, called `expect` to handle interactive CLI programs, where you have to wait for the next prompt, before entering the second value, and I guess you can even branch under conditions.

Comment: `echo` solution looks nice too. It's actually a PHP CLI script, but I follows roughly the same format as your example, so I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

edit: example added

```
  
#!/bin/bash  
USER="root"  
HOST="192.168.1.111"  
PASS="secret"  
expect -c "  
spawn ssh $USER@$HOST  
expect \"password:\"  
send \"$PASS\r\"  
interact  
"
```

--from [this](http://slashraul.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/embedding-expect-inside-of-bash/) blog

Comment: But then you have to write a whole expect script? I was hoping I could just stuff in some command-line args, or pipe it through some program without writing a whole secondary script. Maybe I was just dreaming though.

Comment: check the edit...it's not a whole different script exactly as it's still inside the same bash script

Comment: Except I was writing a PHP CLI script, not a CLI script. Although I could probably shell_exec it...not sure if it would work like that or not though. Oh well.